# Seperating points in the complex plane

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-numbers

Given a finite set of points say $p_1,p_2, \ldots, p_n$ in the complex plane, how do I find another point $q$ such that ray $R_i$ joining $q$ to $p_i$ are all distinct.

I would be happy with any kind of answer, algorithmic or existential.

Comment: If $R_i = R_j$, how does that constrain the location of $q$?

Comment: I guess you just need to make sure that your point $q$ is non-collinear with any two of the $p_k$s. So, take the set of all lines formed by pairs of the $p_k$s and choose some point $q$ not on any of those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L$ be the union over all $i \neq j$ of the lines through $p_{i}$ and $p_{j}$; this is a finite union, so is not the entire plane. Let $q$ be an element of the complement of $L$. For each $i$, the *line* through $q$ and $p_{i}$ contains only one of your points (namely $p_{i}$), so the rays are distinct.

Comment: I thought I said that. :)  And, why wiki?

Comment: @MarkMcClure: By the time I'd finished typing, you'd posted your comment. Wikifying was a compromise between deleting my answer and stealing yours. :)

Comment: Ahh... That makes perfect sense.  I've occasionally answers posted as community wiki and never really understood why.  For the record, it wouldn't have bother me at all.  Unless, the post goes unexpectedly viral. :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Why post an answer as a comment? Post it as an answer. user86418 is doing the right thing: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments

Comment: @Aryabhata You are absolutely correct, of course. I didn't mean to imply that he hadn't done the right thing.  I was mainly curious why he made it CW. For my part, my comment was not of the quality that I would generally post as an answer but, I thought, potentially relevant.  Thus, I posted it as a comment - one that I might or might not have expanded to an answer.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Yeah, I guessed that (smiley and all :)). Just wanted to make you aware of that meta thread, that's all. There are reasons to post an answer instead of a comment, even if you think it is trivial etc. Sorry if my comment sounded like an accusation. It was not.